# Sharepoint list workflow stuck

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

I have written a Sharepoint workflow that starts automatically when an item is created. It has two stages. The first stage sets a yes/no field to yes. then transitions to stage 3(Got rid of stage 2). The workflow gets stuck in stage 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The workflow might require the item to be checked out before it can update the yes/no field.

It would helpful to know what version of SharePoint you are running, along with how the workflow was created, (e.g. Designer or Visual Studio)